# XsltListViewWebPart with dynamic query

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, connected-web-parts

I have to prepare .aspx page with XsltListViewWebPart, which query depends on currently logged user. The query is complicated (querying over 3 lists..., I must find  my juniors in Department user hierarchy list and filter Invoice list if MultiUserField App_Members contains >1 of my juniors = Inovices I am responsible for). Goal is to show page, where filtered XsltListViewWebPart act as a "Master control" and related items/infopath forms/previewers are connected into it as "related controls". How to solve it, please ?

- If I develop programtically Web part  , which contains XsltListViewWebPart as a control included, I will loose all connections and I must handle it my own way.
- If I add XsltListViewWebPart to page FilteredView.aspx using SPLimitedWebPartManager, I think there only static query can be saved...

Comment: XsltListViewWebPart can be used to query against one list only.

Comment: Thanks, yes OK. I am querying only 1 list - in final. But at the beginning, I must find all my juniors. So query snippet will looks like:                 
select * from Invoice where (App_Members contains 'John' .or. App_Members contains 'Jane' ....)

Answer (score 0):

`XsltListViewWebPart` displays a view of a list. Period. If you can't filter out items by using out-of-the-box functionality (configuring the view), then you need a custom web part. You can start by looking into `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart` class. What you will need to do is override `CreateChildControls()`. There you will be able to query as many lists and do whatever checks you want. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms452873%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [this](http://www.concurrency.com/blog/create-a-custom-web-part-for-sharepoint-2010/) are good resources to start with. 2010 is the same as 2013 from that point of view.

Comment: Thank you for resources. As I wrote before, if I develop web part programatically, I have to handle all type of connections, because my web part will act as a "Master". And its a problem to handle connection "Get Form from" for Infopath connected web part . It's historically done. I cannot remove this Infopath web part from page.